# How to Invoke Click on this Button in WebBrowser

Tags: html, vb.net, button, webbrowser-control

**Here is the HTML Button...**

```
<div class="submitBtnContainer">

<button class="nf-btn nf-btn-primary nf-btn-solid nf-btn-align-undefined nf-btn-oversize" type="button" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" placeholder="planSelection_button_continue"><!-- react-text: 186 -->CONTINUE<!-- /react-text --></button>

</div>
```

**I'm try this code...**

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
If Element.OuterHtml.Contains("submitBtnContainer") Then
Element.InvokeMember("click")
Return
End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting elements of tag "a" which is the anchor tag.  From what I can see, there are no anchor tags (URL links).  I suggest you replace "a" with "button" which is the tag of the button itself.

Comment: Unfortunately... Dont work... :/ The button on WebBrowser is Blue but in Google Chrome is Red, i don't know if this is important.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to click the button itself, you cannot click any other elements and expect it to work. Currently you are trying to click an `<a>` (anchor) element, also known as a link.

Iterate all `<button>` tags and check their text instead.

```vb
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
    If Element.InnerText = "CONTINUE" Then
        Element.InvokeMember("click")
        Exit For 'Stop looping.
    End If
Next
```